# R Shiny App access variables from embedded Jotform HTML code with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, r, shiny, shinyjs

I have created a form with [Jotform](https://www.jotform.com/) that I would like to embed in my R Shiny App.

Using shinyjs (?), I would like to access the information filled in the form by the user for using it somewhere else in my Shiny App.

For example, in the minimal example here below, there is a textbox to fill with phone number : can a javascript piece of code allow me to print the phone number in the `server` shiny function ?

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)


ui <- fluidPage(
  myform
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  ### how can I access the phone number stored in the form ?
# runjs('var phone_number = ???????;') 
  # print(input$phone_number)
  
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

where `myform` is the HTML code of the form built with Jotform :

```
myform <- HTML('<script src="https://cdn01.jotfor.ms/static/prototype.forms.js?3.3.39102" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn02.jotfor.ms/static/jotform.forms.js?3.3.39102" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script defer src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/punycode/1.4.1/punycode.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript">   JotForm.newDefaultTheme = true;
      JotForm.extendsNewTheme = false;
      JotForm.singleProduct = false;
      JotForm.newPaymentUIForNewCreatedForms = false;
      JotForm.newPaymentUI = true;
      
      JotForm.init(function(){
        /*INIT-START*/
          setTimeout(function() {
            $(\'input_11\').hint(\'ex: myname@example.com\');
          }, 20);
        if (window.JotForm && JotForm.accessible) $(\'input_6\').setAttribute(\'tabindex\',0);
        /*INIT-END*/
      });
      
      JotForm.prepareCalculationsOnTheFly([null,null,null,null,null,null,{"name":"requestingInformation","qid":"6","text":"Requesting Information Regarding","type":"control_textarea"},{"name":"7","qid":"7","text":"Submit Form","type":"control_button"},null,null,{"name":"name","qid":"10","text":"Name","type":"control_fullname"},{"name":"email11","qid":"11","subLabel":"example@example.com","text":"E-mail","type":"control_email"},{"name":"phoneNumber12","qid":"12","text":"Phone Number","type":"control_phone"},{"name":"clickTo","qid":"13","text":"Information Request","type":"control_head"}]);
      setTimeout(function() {
        JotForm.paymentExtrasOnTheFly([null,null,null,null,null,null,{"name":"requestingInformation","qid":"6","text":"Requesting Information Regarding","type":"control_textarea"},{"name":"7","qid":"7","text":"Submit Form","type":"control_button"},null,null,{"name":"name","qid":"10","text":"Name","type":"control_fullname"},{"name":"email11","qid":"11","subLabel":"example@example.com","text":"E-mail","type":"control_email"},{"name":"phoneNumber12","qid":"12","text":"Phone Number","type":"control_phone"},{"name":"clickTo","qid":"13","text":"Information Request","type":"control_head"}]);}, 20); 
      </script>
        <style type="text/css">@media print{.form-section{display:inline!important}.form-pagebreak{display:none!important}.form-section-closed{height:auto!important}.page-section{position:initial!important}}</style>
          <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn01.jotfor.ms/themes/CSS/5e6b428acc8c4e222d1beb91.css?themeRevisionID=5f30e2a790832f3e96009402"/>
            <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn02.jotfor.ms/css/styles/payment/payment_styles.css?3.3.39102" />
              <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn03.jotfor.ms/css/styles/payment/payment_feature.css?3.3.39102" />
                <style type="text/css" id="form-designer-style">
                  /* Injected CSS Code */
                  .form-label.form-label-auto {
                    
                    display: inline-block;
                    float: left;
                    text-align: left;
                    
                  }
                /* Injected CSS Code */
                  </style>
                  
                  <form class="jotform-form" action="https://submit.jotformeu.com/submit/230374328498363/" method="post" name="form_230374328498363" id="230374328498363" accept-charset="utf-8" autocomplete="on"><input type="hidden" name="formID" value="230374328498363" /><input type="hidden" id="JWTContainer" value="" /><input type="hidden" id="cardinalOrderNumber" value="" />
                    <div role="main" class="form-all">
                      <style>
                      .form-all:before
                    {
                      background: none;
                    }
                    </style>
                      <ul class="form-section page-section">
                        <li id="cid_13" class="form-input-wide" data-type="control_head">
                          <div class="form-header-group  header-large">
                            <div class="header-text httal htvam">
                              <h1 id="header_13" class="form-header" data-component="header">Information Request</h1>
                                </div>
                                </div>
                                </li>
                                          <li class="form-line" data-type="control_phone" id="id_12"><label class="form-label form-label-left form-label-auto" id="label_12" for="input_12_area"> Phone Number </label>
                                            <div id="cid_12" class="form-input" data-layout="half">
                                              <div data-wrapper-react="true"><span class="form-sub-label-container" style="vertical-align:top" data-input-type="areaCode"><input type="tel" id="input_12_area" name="q12_phoneNumber12[area]" class="form-textbox" data-defaultvalue="" autoComplete="section-input_12 tel-area-code" value="" data-component="areaCode" aria-labelledby="label_12 sublabel_12_area" /><span class="phone-separate" aria-hidden="true"> -</span><label class="form-sub-label" for="input_12_area" id="sublabel_12_area" style="min-height:13px" aria-hidden="false">Area Code</label></span><span class="form-sub-label-container" style="vertical-align:top" data-input-type="phone"><input type="tel" id="input_12_phone" name="q12_phoneNumber12[phone]" class="form-textbox" data-defaultvalue="" autoComplete="section-input_12 tel-local" value="" data-component="phone" aria-labelledby="label_12 sublabel_12_phone" /><label class="form-sub-label" for="input_12_phone" id="sublabel_12_phone" style="min-height:13px" aria-hidden="false">Phone Number</label></span></div>
                                                </div>
                                                </li>
                                                
                                                    <li class="form-line" data-type="control_button" id="id_7">
                                                      <div id="cid_7" class="form-input-wide" data-layout="full">
                                                        <div data-align="auto" class="form-buttons-wrapper form-buttons-auto   jsTest-button-wrapperField"><button id="input_7" type="submit" class="form-submit-button submit-button jf-form-buttons jsTest-submitField" data-component="button" data-content="">Submit Form</button></div>
                                                          </div>
                                                          </li>
                                                          <li style="display:none">Should be Empty: <input type="text" name="website" value="" /></li>
                                                            </ul>
                                                            </div>
                                                            <script>
                                                            JotForm.showJotFormPowered = "new_footer";
                                                            </script>
                                                              <script>
                                                              JotForm.poweredByText = "Powered by Jotform";
                                                              </script><input type="hidden" class="simple_spc" id="simple_spc" name="simple_spc" value="230374328498363" />
                                                                <script type="text/javascript">
                                                                  var all_spc = document.querySelectorAll("form[id=\'230374328498363\'] .si" + "mple" + "_spc");
                                                                  for (var i = 0; i < all_spc.length; i++)
                                                                  {
                                                                    all_spc[i].value = "230374328498363-230374328498363";
                                                                  }
                                                                  </script>
                                                                    <div class="formFooter-heightMask"></div>
                                                                      <div class="formFooter f6 branding21">
                                                                        <div class="formFooter-wrapper formFooter-leftSide"><a href="https://www.jotform.com/?utm_source=formfooter&utm_medium=banner&utm_term=230374328498363&utm_content=jotform_logo&utm_campaign=powered_by_jotform_le" target="_blank" class="formFooter-logoLink"><img class="formFooter-logo" src="https://cdn.jotfor.ms/assets/img/logo2021/jotform-logo-white.svg" alt="Jotform Logo" style="height: 44px;"></a></div>
                                                                          <div class="formFooter-wrapper formFooter-rightSide"><span class="formFooter-text">Now create your own Jotform - It\'s free!</span><a class="formFooter-button" href="https://www.jotform.com/?utm_source=formfooter&utm_medium=banner&utm_term=230374328498363&utm_content=jotform_button&utm_campaign=powered_by_jotform_le" target="_blank">Create your own Jotform</a></div>
  </div>
</form><script type="text/javascript">JotForm.ownerView=true;</script><script type="text/javascript">JotForm.forwardToEu=true;</script><script src="https://cdn.jotfor.ms//js/vendor/smoothscroll.min.js?v=3.3.39102"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jotfor.ms//js/errorNavigation.js?v=3.3.39102"></script>')
```

If anyone can help, I would be very grateful !

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please check [this](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/communicating-with-js.html) related article.

Comment: sorry but it doesn't help really help...